# How to dynamically find the position of string in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example:
string= What is <#1#/>?

How to find position of number inside the tag dynamically and how to trim this tag <# #/>?

Comment: Which flavour of SQL are you using (e.g. which RDBMS and version are you using?)

Comment: You could do a replace('<#', '') replace ('#/>','')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find a position of a substring in a string you can use [`CHARINDEX()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

If you want to extract the number from your string you can do

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(s, 
                 CHARINDEX('<#', s) + 2, 
                 CHARINDEX('#/>', s) - CHARINDEX('<#', s) - 2) number
  FROM
(
  SELECT 'What is <#1#/>' s
) q
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17811)** demo